# TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function

Tags: web3js, nodejs, web3-providers

First I connected web3 with Infura. Then reading an ethereum account.

I receive the following error while fetching account balance through node.js console.

```
> web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, bal) => { balance = bal })
TypeError: this.provider.sendAsync is not a function
    at RequestManager.sendAsync (/home/kavi/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:80:19)
    at Eth.send [as getBalance] (/home/kavi/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:141:42)
```

[image: this is the snapshot]

Comment: Please write down a proper question.

Comment: Web3.js v1 has deprecated `sendAsync` for `send` (or vice-versa, so check your web3 version).

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$ node
> const Web3 = require('web3');
> const URL = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/ca689c96846043b18d038f8c97174cf6"    
> const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(URL))
> web3.version.api
'0.20.0'
> const address = "0xa92b75a1349426380edd57b4858674cdb327a30d"
> web3.eth.getBalance(address, (err, wei) => { balance = web3.fromWei(wei, 'ether')})
> balance.toString()
'2089.198909964156321893'
```

If you use web3 version 1.0 use: [web3.utils.fromWei](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#fromwei)